# changing X-Forwarded-For header value using chrome.declarativeNetRequest api?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I modify or add X-Forwarded-For header value using chrome.declarativeNetRequest api? In manifest version 2, it was possible using chrome.webRequest api. But now in manifest version 3, using chrome.declarativeNetRequest api, I can't find anything like this.
For example, I want to implement below code with chrome.declarativeNetRequest api:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(details) {
  const { requestHeaders } = details

  requestHeaders.forEach(header => {
    if (header.name === 'User-Agent') {
      header.value = userAgent
    }
  })

  const headers = requestHeaders.filter(header => {
    return header.name.toLowerCase() !== 'referer'
  })

  return { requestHeaders: headers }
}
},requestFilter,
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) has an example for adding/changing `responseHeaders` and the full reference contains `requestHeaders`. You should add more info to your question to make it answerable.

Comment: sorry for that, I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything that would be helpful for me. I have edited the question with code fragment

Comment: As I said, the documentation has such an example, but you will need to replace responseHeaders with requestHeaders.